# Как перенести iframe в другой элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

На странице с помощью скрипта (виджет) выводится iframe `<iframe id="form_iframe" и т.д.`. Как можно при загрузке страницы с помощью javascript его перенести выше в другой элемент в блок `.content`?
Вот таким образом задача не решается:

```
$("#form_iframe").prependTo(".content");
```

Благодарю!

Comment: iframe вашего домена или чужого? Собственно от этого может зависеть точность ответа

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, более подробно задачю которую вы пытаетесь решеть.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('#form_iframe').clone().prependTo('.content')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function move1() {
  $("#test").prependTo(".content1");
}

function move2() {
  $("#test").prependTo(".content2");
}

move1();
```

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.content1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.content2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content content1"></div>
<div class="content content2"></div>
<button onclick="move1()">Click 1</button>
<button onclick="move2()">Click 2</button>
<br>
<iframe id="test" style="width:130px;height:30px;" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Comment: @LADYX Добавил строчку `move1();`.

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется перенести:

```
$('.content').append($('#form_iframe'));
```

Если клонировать:

```
$('.content').append($('#form_iframe').clone());
```